# How to fix "logging.ini" for python?

Tags: python, logging

I am following the tutorial on logging [HERE](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-logging-in-your-python-application-1730315003c4) and also had a look at the documentation [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format), so I created the following file `logging.ini`:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=extend

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=extend
args=(sys.stdout)

[formatter_extend]
format=%(asctime)s - %(worker)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

which I use in python code as

```
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig(fname='logger.ini')
```

but which results in an error

```
    logging.config.fileConfig(fname='logger.ini')
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/logging/config.py:71: in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/logging/config.py:104: in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py:963: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
E   KeyError: 'formatters'
```

On MacOS, python 3.9.6. Do I miss something?

Comment: It worked for me. Double check there's no typo in the filename - that's the error you'll get if there is. You'll get a different error if you don't have a way of injecting `worker` into the logging event record.

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised because `logging.config.fileConfig` could not find the file called `logger.ini`. Indeed, your conf file is called `logging.ini`.

Instead, do:

```py
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig(fname='logging.ini')
```

or rename `logging.ini` to `logger.ini`.